# The service failed to start due to the following error: The service did not respond to the start or control request in a timely fashion

Tags: c#, .net, windows-services, background-service, worker-service

I created a worker service on .Net 3.1, after I created a windows service in Services.msc, but I can't start the new service. here are all the related errors I found in eventviewer.

1. The TestWorkerService service failed to start due to the following error:
   The service did not respond to the start or control request in a timely fashion.
2. Faulting application name: TestWorkerService.exe, version: 1.0.0.0, time stamp: 0x6243f19c
   Faulting module name: KERNELBASE.dll, version: 6.1.7601.24384, time stamp: 0x5c6e248c
   Exception code: 0xe0434352
   Fault offset: 0x000000000000be0d
   Faulting process id: 0x8778
   Faulting application start time: 0x01d9409075d9a7b9
   Faulting application path: C:\inetpub\TestWorkerService\TestWorkerService.exe
   Faulting module path: C:\Windows\system32\KERNELBASE.dll
   Report Id: b3e4df75-ac83-11ed-a1fc-000c290f795a
3. Application: TestWorkerService.exe
   CoreCLR Version: 4.700.22.30802
   .NET Core Version: 3.1.27
   Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception.
   Exception Info: System.PlatformNotSupportedException: ServiceController enables manipulating and accessing Windows services and it is not applicable for other operating systems.
   at System.ServiceProcess.ServiceBase..ctor()
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.WindowsServices.WindowsServiceLifetime..ctor(IHostEnvironment environment, IHostApplicationLifetime applicationLifetime, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory, IOptions`1 optionsAccessor, IOptions`1 windowsServiceOptionsAccessor)
   at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor, Boolean wrapExceptions)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeConstructorInfo.Invoke(BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitConstructor(ConstructorCallSite constructorCallSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSiteMain(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument) at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitRootCache(ServiceCallSite callSite, RuntimeResolverContext context) at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSite(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.Resolve(ServiceCallSite callSite, ServiceProviderEngineScope scope)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProvider.CreateServiceAccessor(Type serviceType)
   at System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentDictionary`2.GetOrAdd(TKey key, Func`2 valueFactory)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProvider.GetService(Type serviceType, ServiceProviderEngineScope serviceProviderEngineScope)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProvider.GetService(Type serviceType)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetRequiredService(IServiceProvider provider, Type serviceType)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetRequiredService[T](IServiceProvider provider)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.HostBuilder.<>c__DisplayClass35_0.b__2(IServiceProvider _)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitFactory(FactoryCallSite factoryCallSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSiteMain(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument) at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitRootCache(ServiceCallSite callSite, RuntimeResolverContext context) at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSite(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.Resolve(ServiceCallSite callSite, ServiceProviderEngineScope scope)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProvider.CreateServiceAccessor(Type serviceType)
   at System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentDictionary`2.GetOrAdd(TKey key, Func`2 valueFactory)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProvider.GetService(Type serviceType, ServiceProviderEngineScope serviceProviderEngineScope)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProvider.GetService(Type serviceType)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetRequiredService(IServiceProvider provider, Type serviceType)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetRequiredService[T](IServiceProvider provider)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.HostBuilder.ResolveHost(IServiceProvider serviceProvider, DiagnosticListener diagnosticListener)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.HostBuilder.Build()
   at TestWorkerService.Program.Main(String[] args) in C:\Users\a.arabuli\Desktop\intranet\TestWorkerService\Program.cs:line 21

I tried to make a service in a several way like on .net 6.0, 3.1, 2.1, 5.0 on a console application, on a web api, but all the attempts have failed with the same exact errors I mentioned above

Comment: What OS are you on?

Comment: Well the error seems pretty clear:
The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception. Exception Info: System.PlatformNotSupportedException: ServiceController enables manipulating and accessing Windows services and it is not applicable for other operating systems.

Comment: I use windows 10, yes the error message is pretty clear but I cant find a way to fix it, that's why I asked for help

Comment: @jeb While that's true, it would be very odd if OP _were operating on Windows_. Then it would be an indication of a rogue error. I mean some error elsewhere with a different reason, resulting in the observed behavior through some mysterious ways ... and those are hard to find.

Comment: Can you do a proof of concept? Make a new service that does just waste some time and try to start it. Will it? If not, then maybe it's something in your specific way of doing things. If it works, then make it one step more similar to your actual service, test again, and so on. Sooner or later you will then identify the change that causes the error.

Comment: https://github.com/adomelArabuli/workerService

Comment: For testing reason I have already done it I created a stupid service which is logging time. But error is the same, the repo for this service I posted above this comment

Comment: Even I tried to make launch this testService on another pc but the result are same. I am an admin, I am the owner of the app, I have started Interactive services detection in services, and also I have added myself in secpol.msc in log on as a service

Comment: your repo works on my machine. The worker is running

Comment: sc create testService binPath= "path\path.exe" did you use the same way to create a service ?

Comment: @jeb or did you just try to launch exe file ? exe file is launching and worker is logging but I can't start it after registering it as a service in services.msc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to host the worker as a windows service a nuget package is required.
This is the Version 7 for net7.

```
 <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.WindowsServices" Version="7.0.0" />
```

Also you have to include

> UseWindowsService()

```
 public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
            Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .UseSerilog()
            .UseWindowsService()
            .ConfigureServices((hostContext, services) =>
            {
                services.AddHostedService<Worker>();
            });
```

with these changes i was able to run you code as a windows service.

Comment: I have added the nuget you have mentioned about and included the UseWindowsService() (Check the same repo it is updated for now); In the program.cs but I am facing the same issue.

Comment: These packages dont work with 3.1 <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>
it tested it with     <TargetFramework>net7.0</TargetFramework> and it worked.

Comment: I have latest .net 6.0 worth to try? will these packages work with this version ?

Comment: i guess this might work